# Maximizing the smallest eigenvalue of a linear combination of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have an engineering background. At work, I came across the following problem

\begin{align}
&\max_{\lambda,y_i\in \mathbb{R}}~\lambda \\\ 
s.t.~&\left(\mathbf{A}_0+\sum_{i=1}^{K}y_i\mathbf{A}_i\right)-\lambda\mathbf{I} \succeq 0
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{A}_i$ are all Hermitian matrices. I know that this is called a Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) problem and can be solved by a general convex package (e.g., CVX). To me, it seems like we are looking for a matrix formed from the linear combination of given Hermitian matrices whose smallest eigenvalue is as maximum as possible among all such combinations. I was wondering if they are iterative algorithms to solve this problem which are simple to implement. Please point me to relevant references.

Comment: I don't have a solution for this problem, but probably this article could help: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0610026

Comment: This is a semidefinite program.